# Calculating the integral of a function multiplied by two delta functions

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I would like to calculate $\int_{a}^{d}\delta(x-b)\delta(x-c)f(x)dx$, where $a \le b \le d$ and $a \le c \le d$.

My imediate thought is to integrate by parts to obtain
$$\int_{a}^{d}\delta(x-b)\delta(x-c)f(x)dx = [\delta(b-c)f(x)]_{a}^{d} - \int_{a}^{d}\delta(b-c)f'(x)dx$$
$$= \delta(b-c)([f(x)]_{a}^{d} - [f(x)]_{a}^{d}) = 0$$

However, this does not seem correct. Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: For starters, when $b=c$, does $\int \delta^2(x-b)f(x)\,dx$ even have a meaning? Same question for the original when $b\ne c$, actually.

Comment: There is also a nice discussion https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48067/is-square-of-delta-function-defined-somewhere

Answer (score 1):

So I believe the answer can be found using test functions to represent the $\delta$-function. I obtained the general form

$$ \int_a^d \delta(x - b) \delta (x - c) f(x) dx = \delta(b - c) f(c), $$

where $f$ is evaluated at $c$ w.l.o.g as the integral is 0 when $b \ne c$.

Comment: Can I ask how did you get this?

Comment: I proved this using an appropriate test function for each delta distribution (see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), calculating the integral and allowing the asymptotically small value to approach zero. Let me know if you need any more help and I can send you my thesis